# youtube-iframe-api shows Video unavailable for some videos inside iframe

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

For the project purposes, we implemented a youtube player inside the iframe inside out application and it worked for a long period (at least the last 2 years). And now we are facing with an issue for playing some of the videos:
[image]

I followed these instructions https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference to create prototypes with working and not working youtube player

1. Video with Hebrew title in video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-_XAt1OFNI
   https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GU3ERZR46STN

It is not working

If we put the script out of iframe - it works well
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GU3FFVDKFWQR

2. Video with English title in video
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vE1kg4R47N0

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GU3EP4UAIPJE

And it is working well inside the iframe

Comment: I too could not find anything related to this issue because the video plays when I open it on YouTube but it won't play on the iframe player and only says "video unavailable-watch on yotube". Right now I'm just skipping videos that cannot be played because I just cannot waste further time on finding out why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue on a site I'm building with CodeIgniter 4. Some videos play, some show "Video unavailable". It started when I enabled the secure headers filter.. Traced the problem to the Referrer-Policy, so I changed that from 'same-origin' to 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', and now the unavailable videos play just fine.